# many missing dependencies , no links (centOS 7 , postgresql 9.3)

Tags: centos, postgresql

I am trying to install postgresql 9.3 on CentOS 7.

First, I needed to install libxml2, and then I tried to install `libxml2-devel`:

```
$ rpm -iUvh http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxml2-devel-2.9.2-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
xz-devel is needed by libxml2-devel-2.9.2-1.fc19.x86_64
zlib-devel is needed by libxml2-devel-2.9.2-1.fc19.x86_64
```

Although I did install zlib-devel, it is still showing up as a failed dependency.

I am wondering if there's an easier way to do that, since finding links to download those dependencies is really taking time.

Comment: why not installing from epel repo for example but installig fedora package?

Comment: @taliezin I actually did , and it is being installed successfully , however, there's no folders being installed , I followed the documentation here : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation , no new folders are being created

Comment: is there /var/lib/pgsql ?

Comment: there's no   /var/lib/pgsql

Comment: did you run /usr/pgsql-y.x/bin/postgresqlyx-setup initdb ?

Comment: there's no  /usr/pgsql-y.x/bin/ , the folder is not exist

Comment: what is the output of command rpm -qi postgresql?

Comment: it says package is not installed , even though , I did run the command yum install postgresql ,  it says the package has been installed ,but after that , the shell hangs up and stop responding

Comment: try to remove fedora package which you installed.

Comment: This is a cross-post from http://stackoverflow.com/q/29477993/398670

Comment: Actually the package name would be `postgresql-9.3` so `rpm -qi postgresql-9.3` is what you want. Also `ls -ld /usr/pgsql-9.3` and `rpm -qa |grep postgresql` please.

Comment: @CraigRinger , I used another shell , and it is working now , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not just go hunting random RPMs off the Internet like this. You will quickly make your system into an unmaintainable mess.

The correct way to install software on RHEL is to add a *repository* (if necessary) then use `yum` to fetch a package *and all its dependencies* from repositories.

The PostgreSQL project maintains a dedicated yum repository at http://yum.postgresql.org/ with [a how-to page](http://yum.postgresql.org/howtoyum.php).

Once the RPMs are installed, read the `README.rpm-dist` in `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-9.3/` for details on how to proceed with creating the database install, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using yum to do the install? It should allow you to find all the dependencies. You can also use yum to install a local rpm so it is still helpful if you prefer to manually download all the rpms (helpful if you are looking to install specific versions of everything - as long as the dependencies are met).

Comment: I actually did , and it is being installed successfully , however, there's no folders being installed , I followed the documentation here : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation , no new folders are being created